# Elasticsearch query to filter based on list

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Let us say we have following lists in ES. (Each list is part of separate document)

```
[1], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If we query with the list **[1, 2]**, ES should return below results only.

```
[1], [2], [1, 2]
```

Note that using '*terms query*', will return **[1, 2, 3, 4]** also which is not the intended result.

Could someone suggest ES query for this scenario?

Comment: terms is essentially a `contains` operator. Here's elastic's suggestion on how to accomplish what you're looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Additionally, if you know the values you _don't_ want as well, you could bool together some `not` terms.

Comment: @wholevinski Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is that we don't know the values that we don't want.

Comment: One way I could think of is using a bool with OR for your each element and then a script to check  all the matched documents from your query

Answer (score 0):

if the object is mapped as Nested datatype you can search something like listValue is 1, and also is 2, it will result on [1, 2] or [2, 1] because ES doesn't handle orders in simple arrays.

> The nested type is a specialised version of the object datatype that allows arrays of objects to be indexed in a way that they can be queried independently of each other.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/nested.html

Comment: Expectation is that it should also return [1] and [2]. Will your solution help in this case?